# Show scrollbar when mat-dialog appears - Angular Material design

Tags: angular-material

I am using mat-dialog from Angular Material design. When the content is longer the container height, the content in the mat-dialog-content should be scroll.

The scrollbar appears when you scroll down but it disappears after a few seconds. How can I show the scrollbar when the dialog appears? so that users are indicated that there is more content below and they will have to scroll down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following in your dialog component `constructor` to always show vertical scroll on dialog open.

DI Renderer2 to call the `setSyle()` method on the element

```
private ren:Renderer2
```

The CDK overlay is not part of the component and need to grab it from the document.

```
let el = document.getElementsByClassName('mat-dialog-container').item(0);
```

Use Renderer2 to call the `setStyle()` method

```
ren.setStyle(el, 'overflow-y', 'scroll')
```

**Component**

```
import {Component, Inject, Renderer2} from '@angular/core'; 

constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData,
    private ren:Renderer2
    ) {
      let el = document.getElementsByClassName('mat-dialog-container').item(0);
      ren.setStyle(el, 'overflow-y', 'scroll')
     }
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-372fxl?embed=1&file=app/dialog-overview-example.ts

Comment: Thanks Marshal! Appreciated your help!

Comment: setting overflow for .mat-dialog-container class is not enough (not working)

Comment: the provided stackblitz example worked perfectly